# github workflow error when running in github

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm getting an error with this github worklfow:
Doesn't make sense as line 7 is steps: which according to docs is correct

> Invalid workflow file You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 7

```
name: Publish
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  publish:
    name: Publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
      
      - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn
      
      - name: Lint
      run: yarn lint

      - name: Prettier
      run: yarn prettier

      - name: Unit Test
      run: yarn test:coverage

      - name: Cypress
      uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
      with:
        browser: chrome
        headless: true
        start: yarn start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent `uses`/`run` on the same level as `name` without the dash, like so:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: Perfect thanks didn't see that stupid mistake.